# how to compare result of exec to variable

Tags: bash, git

I want to do a comparison for the travis condition

`if [[ <condition> ]]; then <deploy>; fi`

My condition is comparing `git rev-parse HEAD` to `$TRAVIS_COMMIT`

Comment: What do `git rev-parse HEAD` and `$TRAVIS_COMMIT` look like and what sort of comparison are you looking for?

Comment: the are strings of the commit hash. The left is the commit hash of the head commit, and the right is the commit hash of the commit travis is testing.

Comment: I think I got it `“$(git rev-parse HEAD)” == “$TRAVIS_COMMIT” ` thoughts?

Comment: @Mark, better form to use `=` than `==` (since only `=` is guaranteed to work as a string comparison operator with baseline POSIX `[`, being in the habit of using `=` won't mess you up when you're writing code for `/bin/sh`), and it needs to be regular straight quotes, not curly "smart quotes". I do support using `[[ ]]`, vs `[ ]`, since it actually adds advantages over the portable form, but `==` over `=` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Mark, ...btw, to be clear, `if` syntax is `if condition; then`, not `if [[ condition ]]; then`. Any command can be a condition; `[` is a command. (This messes up people who try to write `if [[ grep ... ]]` when it should just be `if grep ...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [[ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" ]]; then
    <deploy>
fi
```

`$(cmd)` captures the output of `cmd` as a string. `[[ ]]` is the best way to do comparisons if you're using Bash. It doesn't require as much quoting as single brackets do: the left side of `==` doesn't need to be quoted here.

Answer (score 0):

You only need single brackets and a single equals sign:

```
if [ "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" = "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" ]; then
    <deploy>
fi
```

This should be more portable. Nevertheless, your proposed solution should work as well.

Comment: Thx for the hint @Charles Duffy. Just copied them :-(